# Rendering performance problem with Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I’m new to Phaser 3 and seem to have a huge performance problem. I’m making a Wordle clone game that renders a grid and fills it in with colors and letters as users progress in the game. Each item in the game is either something I created using this.add.text or this.add.graphics

When the game starts, the scene is able to render in less than 3ms

By the end of the game, the scene takes more than 45ms

What am I doing wrong and why is it so slow? How can I improve the performance?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the code it is hard to tell, for me atleast. A good place to check, is remove  eventlisteners / handlers / emitters, of `inputs` and gameobject, that are not more needed. Although _43ms_ does sound too slow, for a word game.

Comment: btw.: may be you could post your question in this **"forum"** https://phaser.discourse.group/, this is very phaser specific and I think even they main phaser dev posts/responds there sometimes.

Comment: thanks I'll give those things a try

Comment: I believe there some extra-rerender of text objects, Text is one of most (or most?) CPU-consuming GameObject. If you sure that all text renders are required, replace it with BItmapText or maybe just images.